# How to minify CSS and JS in Liferay 7.4? As liferay portal properties are deprecated in 7.4 version

Tags: performance, liferay, liferay-7.4

I've just upgraded our customer's liferay environment from 7.3 to 7.4 CE. In earlier version I was using properties `theme.css.fast.load=true` and `javascript.fast.load=true`. But as liferay says [here](https://learn.liferay.com/dxp/latest/en/liferay-internals/reference/7-4-breaking-changes.html#id12) that these properties are deprecated now. Any idea how to achieve it now?

Answer (score 0):

The document that you link does not contain any mention of "fast.load", but it has a section on Minification:

> #### Disabled Runtime Minification of CSS and JavaScript Resources by Default
>
> ##### What changed?
>
> The `minifier.enable` portal property now defaults to false. Instead of
> performing minification of CSS and JS resources at run time, we
> prepare pre-minified resources at build time. There should be no
> user-visible changes in page styles or logic. Who is affected?
>
> This affects you if your implementations depend on the runtime
> minifier (usually the Google Closure Compiler). How should I update my
> code?
>
> If you want to maintain the former runtime minification behavior, set
> the `minifier.enable` portal property to `true`.
>
> ##### Why was this change made?
>
> Moving frontend resource minification from run time to build time
> reduces server load and facilitates using the latest minification
> technologies available within the frontend ecosystem.

Comment: Yes, it is there, but it doesn't work in liferay 7.4. I've tried in 7.4 GA8 and GA16 (CE) version. Also it contains in portal-properties in Lr source, but not working. 

Ideally it should work once setting minifier.enabled = true